# Reading big data and logistic regression in R

Tags: r, bigdata, regression, logistic-regression, read.table

Situation: 1GB CSV file, 100000 rows, 4000 independent numeric variable, 1 dependent variable.
R on Windows Citrix Server, with 16GB memory.

Problem: It took me 2 hours! to do:

```
read.table("full_data.csv", header=T, sep",")
```

and the glm process crashes, the program is not responding, and I have to shut it down in Task Manager.

Comment: `?read.table` tells you how to make it run faster.  "Process crashes" and "program not responding" are different things; which is it?  How long did you wait before killing R via Task Manager?

Comment: Maybe try [biglm](http://cran.at.r-project.org/web/packages/biglm/index.html)?

Comment: program not responding, 10 mins waiting.

Comment: does biglm support logistic regression?

Comment: or can I read in 1~1000 rows and then 1001~2000 rows and ....? would this make the read in process faster?

Comment: thanks Joshua, seems colClassess option could save some format converting time, is this all I could do?

Comment: Save the data after reading it in to prevent having to read it in again if R crashes. Re. biglm, read the documentation.

Comment: about the slow reading. Is the file you are reading on the local drive or on another network/server (not unlikely since you mention you are already working on a Citrix server)? If the latter, can you first create a local copy?

Comment: general hints: `data.table::fread`; `biglm` package includes `bigglm`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I often resort to the package `sqldf` to load large .csv in memory. A good pointer is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1820610/986817).